# how do I append a file of numbers with both integers and decimals to a list/array in python

Tags: python, list, file

```
f = open(sys.argv[1])
knapSackValues = f.read()
values = []
for number in knapSackValues:
    if(number != ','):
        values.append(number)
print(values)
f.close()
```

This is my code, but the list is not how I want it to be.

My input is

```
5 10.5
3.25 2 5 4.5 7
10.5 4.25 3.75 4.5 8
```

I want it to be so that each of these values is an element of the list/array.

Right now the output is messed up, and this is what pulls up.

```
['5', ' ', '1', '0', '.', '5', '\n', '3', '.', '2', '5', ' ', '2', ' ', '5', ' ', '4', '.', '5', ' ', '7', '\n', '1', '0', '.', '5', ' ', '4', '.', '2', '5', ' ', '3', '.', '7', '5', ' ', '4', '.', '5', ' ', '8']
```

Comment: Not sure if this answers your question but you might want to take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/43474224/1878262 also as far as whitespace is concerned you may want to trim with something like `rstrip()` and consider using `number.split(",")`

Answer (score 1):

You can read the file like this then simply use .split()

```py
with open ('test.txt') as f:
    f = f.read().split()
    print(f)

['5', '10.5', '3.25', '2', '5', '4.5', '7', '10.5', '4.25', '3.75', '4.5', '8']
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete the loop and replace with:

```
values = knapSackValues.split()
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try as below by reading the lines.

```
f = open("./numbers.txt")
knapSackValues = f.readlines()
values = []
for number in knapSackValues:
    values.extend(number.split(" "))
print(values)
f.close()

>>>['5', '10.5', '3.25', '2', '5', '4.5', '7', '10.5', '4.25', '3.75', '4.5', '8']
```

Or Just remove loop and use split() as @purple mentioned

```
values = knapSackValues.split()

>>>['5', '10.5', '3.25', '2', '5', '4.5', '7', '10.5', '4.25', '3.75', '4.5', '8']
```